# Fetching data into redux with useEffect and async/await doesn't work the first time

Tags: react-native, redux

I am fetching data from firestore into a redux store.

So I have the following async function which authenticates the user and then fetches app data after authentication. Content is then supposed to show on complete.

But it only works after refreshing at least twice, and doesn't work on first render and doesn't work immediately after authentication.

I have experimented with different promise combinations, and different dependencies(empty array`[]` and also different fetch statuses(idle, success, pending as used in redux thunks)), but nothing helps.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  const [loadingAppDataComplete, setLoadingAppDataComplete] = useState(false)

  const [stillFetchingData, setStillFetchingData] = useState('idle')

  const canFetchData = (stillFetchingData === 'idle' && !loadingAppDataComplete)

  async function loadAppData() {
    if (canFetchData) {
      try {
        setStillFetchingData('pending')

        const authResponse = await loadAuth()

        const dataStatusCheck = await fetchAppData(authResponse)

        console.log(dataStatusCheck)

      } catch {
        console.log("something went wrong")
      } finally {
        setStillFetchingData('idle')
        setLoadingAppDataComplete(true)
      }
    } 

  }


  useEffect(() => {
    loadAppData()
  }, [
    authObject,
    postsStatus,
    usersStatus,
  ])
```

`loadAuth` authenticates the user on firestore and then logs the user into the redux store.

```
export default async function loadAuth() {
    try {
       
        firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                const uid = String(user.uid)
                console.log("logged user with id " + uid)
                Store.dispatch(logUser({ emailAddress: user.email, userId: uid, loggedIn: true }))
                
            }
        })

    } catch {
        console.log("loading the user failed")
    } finally {
        return Store.getState().authObject
    }
}
```

The user is logged into an authentication slice in the redux store

```
const authenticationSlice = createSlice({
    name:'authentication',
    initialState: authObject,
    reducers:{
        logUser:(state, action) => {
            Object.assign(state, action.payload)
        },
    }
})
```

And `fetchAppData` just fetches the users and posts, and then similarly creates a slice for each.

```
export default async function fetchAppData(authCheck) {
    if (authCheck?.loggedIn) {
        try {

            if (Store.getState().posts.status === 'idle') {
                await Store.dispatch(fetchPosts())
            }

            if (Store.getState().users.status === 'idle') {
                await Store.dispatch(fetchUsers())
            }


            if (Store.getState().draftPosts.status === 'idle') {
                await Store.dispatch(fetchDraftPosts(authObject?.userId))
            }

    
        } catch {
            console.log("could not fetch users and posts and drafts")
        } finally {
            return("; postsStatus " + Store.getState().posts.status
                + "; usersStatus " + Store.getState().users.status
                + "; draftPostsStatus " + Store.getState().draftPosts.status
            )
       
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What loadAuth() and fetchAppData() do? When and where do you insert data at Redux store ?  Please provide more information.

Comment: @Alexios, I added the loadAuth() and the fetchAppData(). Data is inserted in the redux store while they are running

Comment: @Kat I don't think you should ever use store in your code except when you export it after calling createStore.

Comment: @HMR, yes, I tried to avoid doing it, but that would mean loading data from the first screen, instead of from App.js -- in App.js, I don't have access to the store's provider.  But even if I load data from the first screen, I would still have to use store directly to authenticate? Do you have recommendations on where is the best place to fetch data and dispatch to store?

Comment: @Kat You can use thunk to fetch data, in components you can use the react-redux hooks useSelector and useDispatch.